# Cannot create VirtualEnv with Python 3.7 and Anaconda - No such file or directory: site.py

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

Trying to create a virtual environment within a project for work...

`conda update virtualenv`

`virtualenv venv`

Returns the following:

```
Using base prefix 'C:\\Users\\njho\\Anaconda3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\njho\Anaconda3\Scripts\virtualenv-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\njho\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 712, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "C:\Users\njho\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 927, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "C:\Users\njho\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1149, in install_python
    writefile(site_filename_dst, SITE_PY)
  File "C:\Users\njho\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 363, in writefile
    with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\njho\\Documents\\companyX\\projectX\\venv\\python37.zip\\site.py'
```

Does anyone know what's happening here? I've used `virtualenv` fairly recently without issue. The directory it's looking in is within my project, and hasn't been created yet.

This is how the directory looks like at time of crash - we can see that obviously the file doesn't exist...:

[image]

Thanks!